# Wait for external function to complete inside cycle

Tags: python, wait, cycle

I don't know python very well and am stuck on one problem(
I'm running a function in a loop from an external python file (inference.py), and I don't know how to make the program wait for that function to finish until the next iteration of the loop.
After running the code, I get a message:

> An attempt has been made to start a new process before the current
> process has finished its bootstrapping phase. This probably means that
> you are not using fork to start your child processes and you have
> forgotten to use the proper idiom in the main module:
>
> ```
>         if __name__ == '__main__':
>             freeze_support()
>             ...
> ```
>
> The "freeze_support()" line can be omitted if the program is not going
> to be frozen to produce an executable.

I understand I need to use wait() and fork() methods, but I don't understand how. I'd appreciate your advice.

```
import os
import glob
import inference

video_names = glob.glob(os.path.join("input", "*.mp4"))
num_videos = len(video_names)

for ind, input_video in enumerate(video_names):
    output_green_screen = os.path.join(
            "output", os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(input_video))[0] + "_green_screen.mp4"
        )
    output_matte = os.path.join(
            "output", os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(input_video))[0] + "_matte.mp4"
        )
    inference.convert_video(
        model,
        device = "cuda",
        downsample_ratio = 0.4,
        input_source = input_video,
        output_type = "video",
        output_composition = output_green_screen,
        output_alpha = output_matte,
        output_video_mbps = 8, 
        seq_chunk = 4,
        num_workers = 1,
        progress = True
    )
```

Comment: Have you tried removing the ```freeze_support()``` line and see if that helps?

Comment: I don't use freeze_support() in the code, it's a command line message

Comment: Ok but have you tried not sending it then?

Comment: I don't know what you mean(

Comment: You send the freeze_support() command through the command line, have you tried not sending it?

Comment: I'm not sending the freeze_support() command through the command line, it is just warning message from python. I'm runing inference.convert_video() function